# How can I setup a scheduled sync from a SQL Server database to Salesforce Big Objects?

Tags: integration, c#, .net, sqlserver, big-object

What is the best way to have a daily scheduled insert/update of a SQL Table into Salesforce Big Objects? We currently have a C# adapter to update Salesforce standard object records with SQL database data, but I'm not sure if this same approach will work for Big Objects.

If anyone could elaborate on the best way(s) to integrate a SQL database with Salesforce Big Objects, that would be super helpful. Open to C#/.Net implementations ([we use this currently](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET)), SQL Server connectors/adapters, 3rd party connector platforms, anything. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that you will need to use the SOAP Bulk API to populate the Big Objects. This typically means having the data to upsert in CSV format and including the index.

See [Populate a Custom Big Object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bigobjects.meta/bigobjects/big_object_populate.htm).

In the [Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET#bulk-sample-code) this should correspond to the `BulkForceClient`